# Compute column of balances from deposit and withdrawal using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate excess cash based on withdrawn amount and replenished amount column in a pandas data frame.

To calculate excess cash the logic is whenever there has been replenishment take difference of replenished amount with withdrawn amount. Rows where no replenishment has taken place use previous row's excess cash to take difference with the amount withdrawn of current row.

Example:

```
   Withdrawn  Replenished
0         10           80
1         20            0
2         30            0
3         10            0
4         20           30
```

As shown in above table I've used the following code to calculate excess cash based on logic that whenever there has been replenishment take difference of Replenished column with Withdrawn amount.

```
df['Excess'] = 0

df['Excess'] = np.where(df['Replenished'] > 0, df['Replenished'] - df['Withdrawn'], 0)
```

Now the second part is where I am facing the problem. Rows where Replenished column is `0`. I need to use previous row's excess cash and take difference with current row's withdrawn amount. For that I've used the following code:

```
df['Excess'] = np.where(df['Replenished'] == 0, df['Excess'].shift(1) - df['Withdrawn'], df['Excess'])
```

It results in the following table:

```
   Withdrawn  Replenished  Excess
0         10           80    70.0
1         20            0    50.0
2         30            0   -30.0
3         10            0   -10.0
4         20           30    10.0
```

For the first time when Replenished column is `0` (2nd Row) the calculation works correctly. But in the third and fourth row where value in column named Replenished is `0`, since the previous row is `0` after subtracting previous row's excess cash with current row's withdrawn value, I get `-30` and `-10` respectively.

Following is the desired output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| Withdrawn | Replenished | Excess |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
|        10 |          80 |     70 |
|        20 |           0 |     50 |
|        30 |           0 |     20 |
|        10 |           0 |     10 |
|        20 |          30 |     10 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for multiple Replenishments as well. Perform a cumulative sum of "Replenished" and "Withdrawn", then subtract one from the other:

```
cum_deposit = df.groupby(df['Replenished'].ne(0).cumsum())['Withdrawn'].cumsum()
df['Excess'] = df['Replenished'].replace(0, np.nan).ffill() - cum_deposit
df

   Withdrawn  Replenished  Excess
0         10           80    70.0
1         20            0    50.0
2         30            0    20.0
3         10            0    10.0
4         20           30    10.0
```

Comment: As stated in the question on days where replenishment has taken place I just need to subtract the Replenished amount of current row (not the cumsum) with the Withdrawn amount of that row. According to your logic on days where Replenishment has taken place it would incorporate previous row's excess amount and sum it with replenished amount of current row and then taken difference with current row's Withdrawn amount.

Comment: @FurqanHashim With your current dataset it isn't obvious to me why this is incorrect, and I didn't understand your explanation very well. Could you update your sample data and expected output with some more rows explaining why this solution would not work please? I know it's a little work for you but it is necessary for me to give you a 100% correct solution. Thanks.

Comment: @FurqanHashim Random idea: Perhaps `df['Excess'] = df['Replenished'].replace(0, np.nan).ffill() - df['Withdrawn'].cumsum()` will do what you want?

Comment: on row's where there is replenishment I just need to subtract and replenished amount with withdrawn amount to compute excess. But as per your solution it adds on row where there is replenishment even though it subtracts current row's replenishment with withdrawn but add previous row's excess value to the difference which I don't want. On days where there is replenishment just subtract replenishment with withdrawn. I've edited my question and added a new example to make it more clear.

Comment: @FurqanHashim Thanks for the clarification. I've understand what you need. Please see my edit.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. If you don't mind can you please explain this piece of code `df.groupby(u)['Withdrawn']` what is it doing?

Comment: @FurqanHashim I am grouping consecutive rows associated with a particular replenishment, then taking the cumulative sum of withdrawals for those rows only.

Comment: If same replenishment amount is repeated how can we deal with that? The logic fails in that case.

Comment: @FurqanHashim Edited my solution, the grouper for "replenished" has changed.